# Call OnResume when Back Button Pressed when using Fragments

Tags: android, fragment

I add first fragment like this

```
            FragmentManager fm = SliderActivity.this
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            ft.add(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, "Home");
                ft.addToBackStack("Home");
                ft.commit();
```

and second fragment as

```
            FragmentManager fm = SliderActivity.this
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            ft.add(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, "About");
            ft.addToBackStack("About");
            ft.commit();
```

My question is if I press back button from AboutFragment (Second) then how to call a method of HomeFragment (First)

```
            onResume() is not fired which is creating problem
```

Comment: Please check my answer with add() call, that will help you

Answer (score 6):

I am posting late answer, but i think this will be useful for others

While we are using `add()` with Fragment transactions, `onResume()` will not be called on **Source** fragment. Only **Destination** fragment will get `onResume()` callback

But using this way, we can achieve `onResume()` callback to **Source** fragment :

Add this in Host Activity's `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()
                .get(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).onResume();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Note : Be sure that you have called `addToBackStack()` with `commit()`

This code will give `onResume()` callback to **Source** fragment

Thank you

Comment: `getFragments()` should not be called from outside the `com.android.support` package. Otherwise it would have been an acceptable solution.

Comment: it is called on `getSupportFragmentManager()` instance... so will work always

Comment: I don't think its a good practice to manually call any of the fragment's life cycle callbacks manually

Comment: Agree, but for this requirement, we can simulate onResume like this way

Answer (score 0):

i am using this method for all my fragment a

```
// For the Fragment Replace And AddtobackStack
    void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        String fragmentTag = backStateName;

        FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager
                .popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

        if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null) {
            // fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentTag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commit();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling "add" for the second fragment use "replace instead"

i.e. instead of

```
ft.add(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, "Home");
```

use

```
ft.replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, "Home");
```

So whenever u will press back button to go previous fragment, the first fragment's lifecycle will be called back again.

**OR** if it doesnt meet ur requirement, u can do this:

```
private final static String TAG_FRAGMENT = "TAG_FRAGMENT";

private void showFragment() {
final Myfragment fragment = new MyFragment();
final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
final Myfragment fragment = (Myfragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);

if (fragment.allowBackPressed()) { // and then you define a method allowBackPressed with the logic to allow back pressed or not
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding fragment

```
ft.add(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, "About");
```

then it'll not call any method of first fragment on back press.

To call the method of the first fragment, instead replace the fragment with :

```
ft.replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, "About");
```

But this will call `onCreateView()` first then other methods.It is not possible in fragment on backpressed to call `onResume()`, as in activity happens

Comment: cant use replace since I want to have previous fragment on back

Comment: nd y u want to keep that fragment on back? check my answer, i have another option if u dont want to use replace

Comment: It will be.replace doesn't remove fragment from backstack what it does call fragment from onCreateView() and .add will just add one fragment over the other