# Which method is called when back button is pressed from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I've had a look at this question-
[Call OnResume when Back Button Pressed when using Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732839/call-onresume-when-back-button-pressed-when-using-fragments)

I've done the same things, as mentioned in the answers, but neither is onResume called, nor onCreateView. It's a transaction from an activity to a fragment, all of which are a part of a single tab. How can I call a method from the first fragment when back button is pressed on the second fragment?

Code-

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("q", code);
data.putString("type", type);
data.putString("name", name);

viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = 
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
eq equity = new eq();
equity.setArguments(data);
transaction.replace(R.id.root_frame, equity).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: is the back button is the only way for leaving the fragment?

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method called when you press the back button is onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (yourCondition = true) {
        //do something here
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

But onOptionsItemSelected is called on the parent activity.

I don't know if the back button is required, but I think it's better to implement a callback from one fragment to the other with an Interface and using a custom button not the back button.

Comment: I think you got the question wrong. I'm sorry for not being clear enough. I'm looking to call a function in the activity, not in the fragment. So, which method is called in the `Activity` when it loads after pressing the back button?

Answer (score 0):

fragment life cycle is directly effected by the host's activity life cycle so you gotta take that in consideration anyway did you try to call the method in `onPuase()` or in `onStart()` in the fragment that you are heading for after pressing back ? if that didn't work try to reach the emulator back button from `if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)` or you can `finish()` the previous fragment or activity so the back button will get the user no where and create your own back button to redirect the user and replace the method in it using `onClick()` .
hope that will work for you good luck